# Merge-Delete Macro for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet containing transcripts from various television shows.  As you can see, each time the speaker changes, they are introduced as "BURNETT:" or "HANNITY:".  I need a way to merge all the cells that follow a particular speaker so that their speech is all contained within one Excel cell.  I tried text-to-columns saving as a CSV and doing a find-replace, but of course that didn't work.

For instance, I need this...

```
NETWORK SHOW    DATE    TIME    TIMEBLOCK   SPEAKER SPEAKTURN
CNN OUTFRONT    2011-12-05  19:00   19:00           ERIN BURNETT OUTFRONT
CNN OUTFRONT    2011-12-05  19:00   19:00           ERIN BURNETT, HOST: Thanks, John. We're live from the Middle East…
CNN OUTFRONT    2011-12-05  19:00   19:00           Let's go OUTFRONT.
CNN OUTFRONT    2011-12-05  19:00   19:00           I'm Erin Burnett and I'm OUTFRONT tonight live from Abu Dhabi in…
CNN OUTFRONT    2011-12-05  19:00   19:00           Now Iran claims that it shot down an American drone that looks a…
CNN OUTFRONT    2011-12-05  19:00   19:00           If this really happened, that means that technology is in the han…
CNN OUTFRONT    2011-12-05  19:00   19:00           So far recently we've had Israel threatening to bomb Iranian nucl…
CNN OUTFRONT    2011-12-05  19:00   19:00           Iran is defiant, and a defiant Iran could mean surging oil prices…
CNN OUTFRONT    2011-12-05  19:00   19:00           Robin Mills is author of "The Myth of the Oil Crisis". Riad Kahwa…
CNN OUTFRONT    2011-12-05  19:00   19:00           RIAD KAHWAJI, FOUNDER, INST. MILITARY ANALYSIS: Well, I think…
CNN OUTFRONT    2011-12-05  19:00   19:00           BURNETT: Teetering.
```

To become this...

```
NETWORK SHOW    DATE    TIME    TIMEBLOCK   SPEAKER  SPEAKTURN
CNN OUTFRONT    2011-12-05  19:00   19:00            ERIN BURNETT OUTFRONT
CNN OUTFRONT    2011-12-05  19:00   19:00            ERIN BURNETT, HOST: Thanks, John. <<all the intervening text in the rows in between>> Robin Mills is author of "The Myth of the Oil Crisis." Riad Kahwa…
CNN OUTFRONT    2011-12-05  19:00   19:00            RIAD KAHWAJI, FOUNDER, INST. MILITARY ANALYSIS: Well, I think…
CNN OUTFRONT    2011-12-05  19:00   19:00            BURNETT: Teetering.
```

See how Erin Burnett's speaking turn is now contained within one cell and the other rows have been deleted?  I need a macro that does that.

From there, I can make it look like this by using text-to-columns function and deleting all the rows that don't have a name in the SPEAKER column.  This would be the final goal, but I can do these steps (yeah, I know, leaving you the hard part).

```
NETWORK SHOW    DATE    TIME    TIMEBLOCK   SPEAKER                                               SPEAKTURN
CNN OUTFRONT    2011-12-05  19:00   19:00   ERIN BURNETT, HOST                                    Thanks, John. <<intervening text>> Robin Mills is author of "The Myth of the Oil Crisis." Riad Kahwa…
CNN OUTFRONT    2011-12-05  19:00   19:00   RIAD KAHWAJI, FOUNDER, INST. FOR MILITARY ANALYSIS    Well, I think…
CNN OUTFRONT    2011-12-05  19:00   19:00   BURNETT                                               Teetering.
```

The worksheet, should you desire it, is available here on [Wikisend](http://wikisend.com/download/643834/CleanMS.xlsx) for the next week.

For what it's worth, I'm pretty sure that any script that recognizes a cell as introducing a new speaker would need to just see that there were at least four consecutive capital letters eventually followed a colon (I say eventually, because of the titles and occupations given the first time they speak).  Then it could look down the column until it finds another such cell.  It would then concatenate the contents (inserting spaces in between each) of all the cells between the "found" cells, and delete the rows that no longer had any SPEAKTURN data in them.

Finally, I should apologize.  I know that the expectation on Stackoverflow is that I should do ample research,  but I am coming up on a deadline, and I don't know where else to turn.  I learned how to trip-stumble my way through R over the course of a month last semester, but as a Political Science major way out of my league, I can't for the life of me learn enough VBA to do this by Tuesday. :: hanging head in shame ::

Without a macro to do this, I'll have to spend a several days merging more than 8,000 cells.  I'm desperate.  If you desire compensation---I'm a poor college senior trying to do a Communications senior project---I will do my best.  I'm just at my wits end here.

PS If you want to know why I need this... WELL, I will be scoring each of the speaking turns for the presence or absence of 13 types of manipulative tactics by TV show hosts: (1) insulting language, (2) name calling, (3) emotional displays, (4) emotional language, (5) verbal fighting/sparring, (6) character assassination, (7) misrepresentative exaggeration, (8) mockery/sarcasm, (9) conflagration, (10) ideologically extremizing language, (11) slippery slope arguments, (12) belittling, and (13) obscene language.  It's all about how cable news shows get people riled up.  8000 rows of that will take a while, which is why I am so desperate for your help.

Comment: How did the project go?

Answer (score 1):

Not many people will help you, you haven't supplied the least bit of vba code to indicate your level of knowledge or that you at least attempted. Plus, you say it is for school, most don't help students do their schoolwork.

I will at least give you a general overview of how to accomplish your task:

```
set excelapp = excel.application
set objwb = excelapp.workbooks.open("C:\yourworkbook.xls")
set objws = objwb.worksheets("yourworksheet")
set newObjws = objwb.worksheets.add()

dim newRow as long
newRow = 1
sc = speechColumn --- you need to insert its number here

for i = 1 to objws.usedrange.rows.count
      newobjws.cells(newrow,sc).value = objws.cells(i,sc)
      'here you would want to copy other columns if you like as well.
      i = i + 1
      do while instr(objws.cells(i,sc).value,":") = 0
            newobjws.cells(newrow,sc).value = newobjws.cells(newrow,sc).value & _
                                              " " & objws.cells(i,sc).value
            'here you would want to copy other columns if you like as well.
            i = i + 1
      loop
      i = i - 1
next i
```

Answer (score 0):

The Wikisend site contains a zip file CleanMS.zip which contains a number of XML files.  I imported "sharedStrings.xml" to Excel.  Column C matches the SPEAKTURN column in your image.

I have tested your theory that if the four characters are capitalised and there is a colon in the string then the characters up to the colon are a name.  I did this by locating such strings and creating a new list in another sheet of the "names".  There are 5500 such "names" and I cannot find any that do not look like a name.  This is out of a total of 8,264 lines.

Merging the lines in the way you seek would be trivial.

However, at the very end you have two apparent "hosts": Bret BAIER and Ed HENRY.  There are lines such as:

```
HENRY (on-camera): Senior officials privately say the last ... -- Bret
About an hour ago, we learned the S&P rating service ...
```

Is the second line by HENRY or BAIER?

If you want me to look at your data more carefully, you need to provide it as an XLS file.

BTW its gone midnight here so I am going to bed.  If you respond, don't expect a reply in the next 8 - 9 hours.

**New section**

I realised while I slept that with minor tweaks my investigative code gives almost all you ask for and perhaps all you need.

Change the two Const statement to address the correct columns and this code will remove the name from the SPEAKTURN column and place it in the SPEAKER column.

This does not merge the text when the speaker has two or more rows but otherwise I think the result is what you seek.  I have tested this on the data I managed to import from Excel but not on the original worksheet so save your data before running this code.

```
Sub ExtractNames()

  Dim PosColon As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowLast As Long
  Dim Stg As String

  ' ##### Replace "C" and "B" with the correct columns
  Const ColSpeakTurn As String = "C"
  Const ColSpeaker As String = "B"

  With Sheets("Sheet1")
    RowLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColSpeakTurn).End(xlUp).Row

    For RowCrnt = 1 To RowLast
      Stg = .Cells(RowCrnt, ColSpeakTurn).Value
      PosColon = InStr(1, Stg, ":")
      If PosColon <> 0 Then
        If UCase(Left(Stg, 4)) = Left(Stg, 4) Then
          ' Looks like a name.
          ' Copy name to Speaker column
          .Cells(RowCrnt, ColSpeaker).Value = Mid(Stg, 1, PosColon - 1)
          ' Remove name and any following spaces from SpeakTurn column
          .Cells(RowCrnt, ColSpeakTurn).Value = Trim(Mid(Stg, PosColon + 1))
          RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1
        End If
      End If
    Next

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm fairly certain that I uploaded and .xslx file.  In any case, I've decided I'm just going to seek help from the Computer Science department.  This was probably not the proper venue for my question.  I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Fine but do try my code.  It separates the names from what people said which is what you wanted.  It does not merge multiple lines for the same speaker but since there are problems with overlong text in a cell that is not necessarily bad.  Wikisend claims the file was an XLSX file but Excel 2007 could not interpret any of the files within the zip file as Excel files.